# Why Content download need so much time?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore with queries and i am getting data but something in network tab is loading none stop

[as you can see its over a minute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSsnP.jpg)
should i be concerned about it?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be certain without seeing the [**code** that produces this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but most likely you're using a realtime listener (`onSnapshot`) in your code.

Such a listener keeps an active , open connection between the client and the server, so that the database can send a notification to the client when the data changes. The Chrome network tool shows this as a content download, because indeed data trickles in over this connection.

So likely what you're seeing is a normal part of Firestore's protocol for realtime, bi-directional communication between the client and server, but again.